# Example of differential equation with two general solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a teaching-related question.

When teaching ordinary differential equations, we typically distinguish between the general solution (which includes unspecified integration constants) and particular solutions (where the integration constants are fixed by, say, initial values).

This makes sense for linear ordinary differential equations. But I can imagine that some nonlinear ordinary differential equations have two different solutions that look nothing like each other, that is, their difference is not an integration constant.

Do you know an example for such differential equations (and solutions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic counterexample is $y' = 2 \sqrt{|y|}$. It has "quadratic" solutions, looking like $y = (x-a)^2$ for $x \geq a$, but also $y = 0$ is a solution. You can patch these two together to obtain a nonunique solution to the initial value problem $y' = 2 \sqrt{|y|}$ and $y(0) = 0$.

It might also be fun to think about solutions to $y'= 2 \sqrt{|y|}$ and $y(0) = \eta$. Is the solution unique in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just multiply together two linear homogeneous ODEs, to form a nonlinear ODE, e.g.

(y'+ay) (y'+by) = 0

This shows explicitly how nonlinear ODEs can have separate solution branches (if a and b are different).